# C++ 3D array to 1D causes heap-buffer-overflow

Tags: c++, arrays, buffer-overflow

I want to give a minimal example. If the code provided is not enough, please tell me what else you need. It's nothing super secret ;)

Consider the following two implementations:

Using 3d array:

.h

```
class Grid
{
    public:
        Grid();

        uint8_t get(int x, int y, int z);
        void set(int x, int y, int z, uint8_t value);

    private:
        uint8_t blocks[Chunk::width][Chunk::height][Chunk::depth];
};
```

.cpp

```
Grid::Grid()
{
    memset(blocks, 0, sizeof(blocks));
}

uint8_t Grid::get(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return blocks[x][y][z];
}

void Grid::set(int x, int y, int z, uint8_t value)
{
    blocks[x][y][z] = value;
}
```

Now a 1D array:

.h

```
class Grid
{
    public:
        Grid();

        uint8_t get(int x, int y, int z);
        void set(int x, int y, int z, uint8_t value);

    private:
        uint8_t blocks[Chunk::width * Chunk::height * Chunk::depth];
        int to1D(int x, int y, int z) { return x + (y * Chunk::width) + (z * Chunk::width * Chunk::height); }
};
```

.cpp

```
Grid::Grid()
{
    memset(blocks, 0, sizeof(blocks));
}

uint8_t Grid::get(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return this->blocks[x + (y * Chunk::width) + (z * Chunk::width * Chunk::height)];
}

void Grid::set(int x, int y, int z, uint8_t value)
{
    this->blocks[x + (y * Chunk::width) + (z * Chunk::width * Chunk::height)] = value;
}
```

Now with the 3D version everything works like a charm, while **for the same overall size** I get a

> SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow src/Grid.cpp:16 in Grid::get(int, int, int)

And I really wonder why that is. Both implementations hold `uint8_t`s... What is the optimization going on in the 3d-array version I cannot seem to see/grasp?

(Yes, this is a minecrafty voxel engine experiment ;))

Comment: how-ish big are the values of width, height, and depth?

Comment: follow up on @Ronin, does your code crash for small values of x/y/z?

Comment: You never stated what values you're calling `Grid::get` with.

Comment: What is your IDE (programming environment and compiler) and what kind of error did you get?

Comment: Values for each are 16. there are a lot oft grids though

Comment: Clang and clion

Answer (score 0):

If you're building an environment for a game, my guess is you're having memory allocation issues. Lets say that you need 50 MB of memory for the game you're running. Getting that 50 MB from anywhere isn't a big deal. But trying to get 50 MB of continuous memory is waaaaaayyy more difficult. Most OS's these days use a paging system to keep track of allocated and unallocated memory. Here's more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging

A 3D array is basically a pointer to a array of pointers, of each of these pointers point to another array of pointers. And each of those pointers contains a finite chunk of memory to interact with. So in this case the OS can give you 5,000 50 KB chunks of memory and the pointers can keep all of this memory in different places.

Comment: I don't think heap memory can provide 50MB, but why continious memory is needed?!

Comment: I just threw a number out there. But basically he's storing all of the info from the 3D array to a 1D array. And 1D arrays are normally allocated a continuous amount of memory that is calculated on declaration.